# Not adjusted (?) trend line, ggplot [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Maybe it's an understanding error but with this [data](https://pastebin.com/EkAAGPFg) and code...

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = T, fullrange = T) +
  ggpubr::stat_cor(label.x = 3) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), 
                labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x)))
```

... I'm getting this plot:

[image]

I'd expect a different trend line (manually drawn in red) and what I'm guessing is that those `-Inf` values are affecting somehow. Anyone could help me to understand the error, please? Thanks.

Comment: The blue trend line is for the log transformed data. If you want a trend line for the untransformed data try with `coord_trans(y = "log10")` instead of scale_y_log10 .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @stefan, but when "visually" inspecting the plot, there're a some `-Inf` values (in the y-axis) that aren't leveraging at all this trend line... aren't they considered for this regression? If not, is there any way to take them account? Thanks again.

Comment: If these values are true infinite values (i.e. y =0 or log(y) = -Inf) then they will be removed by geom_smooth, i.e. they are not taken into account. One option to take them into account would be to replace the zero values with a small positive number, e.g. 1e-12 or ... However, keep in mind that you still will end up with a linear trend line, with a different slope and intercept of course.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that's interesting solution... nevertheless, I'm afraid of modifying so much my data. Thanks for all your help!